# Automate running over 100k different types of jobs daily?

Tags: automation, cron, batch-processing

I am working on a project where I want to create a system which can help me in running over 100k jobs on a daily basis. Configuration should allow to make jobs dependent on each other, they should be rescheduled if failed, should be able to trigger themselves based on an event etc.

Do we have any open source project for this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I am not asking for a recommendation, its an open problem to solve. I am looking for a nice architecture.